# Unity menu search doesn't find manually installed shortcut

Tags: unity, menu, appmenu

Sequence of operations:

1. [install](https://github.com/l0b0/minecraft-scripts/blob/master/install-Minecraft-shortcut-GNOME.sh) a GNOME menu shortcut.
2. Click <kbd>Windows</kbd> to get the Unity search interface.
3. Type in the first few characters of the shortcut name.

Result: The installed shortcut does *not* show up in the list of matches.

However, the shortcut *is installed, accessible, and works*:

1. Click <kbd>Windows</kbd> to get the Unity search interface.
2. Click <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the search interface.
3. Click the "Applications" icon.
4. Type in the first few characters of the shortcut name.

Now the shortcut shows up in the "Most Frequently Used" list, but not in the "Installed" list. It is also shown in the "Main Menu" application. So why doesn't it show up in the default search? Do I somehow have to tag it as "Installed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installed means:

1. It is in the software repositories accessible by the software
   center.
2. A desktop file exists under /usr/share/applications or
   /usr/local/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications

The script you use however installs the desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications that isn't monitored by Unity. Log out or restart unity to pick it up.

It will most likely work out of the box if you run such scripts as root (excerpt from xdg-desktop-menu man page)

> The default is to use system mode when called by root and to use
>   user mode when called by a non-root user.

Comment: *"The script you use however installs the desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications where Unity does not seem to look for applications. Why user mode installations are exempt from look-up I can't tell."* - This is not true. Unity ***does*** find applications that are put in `~/.local/share/applications` but only after logging out and back in or reloading Unity. Such applications are "present", but not "installed" in the technical sense.

Comment: I'll edit my post - then it may be a bug that ~/.local/share/applications isn't monitored with libfam or libgamin? That self compiled apps at /usr/local/share/applications appear as if installed?

Comment: that is no bug, that's just the way things work :)

Comment: Excellent and to the point. Accepted!